# Trying to start an activity is causing an exception to be thrown, unsure why

Tags: java, android, button, android-activity

Here is the code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = new ExpenseIcon(context);

        ((ExpenseIcon) convertView)
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        System.out.println("Expense Icon Clicked");

                        Intent a = new Intent(context, ExpenseInput.class);
                        a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        context.startActivity(a);
                    }
                });
    }

    if (image == null)
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.dollar);

    ((ExpenseIcon)convertView).setImageBitmap(image);

    return convertView;
}
```

When I click on the ExpenseIcon button I get an exception thrown at the line context.startActivity(a):

> 04-28 11:04:53.100: D/AndroidRuntime(24962): Shutting down VM 04-28
>   11:04:53.100: W/dalvikvm(24962): threadid=1: thread exiting with
>   uncaught exception (group=0x41ebc930) 04-28 11:04:53.130:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24962): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 04-28 11:04:53.130:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24962): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling
>   startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the
>   FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:944) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:931) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:284)
>   04-28 11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):  at
>   com.example.mytestapp.controls.ExpenseIconGridGenerate$1.onClick(ExpenseIconGridGenerate.java:63)
>   04-28 11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):  at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204) 04-28 11:04:53.130:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24962):  at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 04-28 11:04:53.130:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24962):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 04-28 11:04:53.130:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24962):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>   04-28 11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 04-28
>   11:04:53.130: E/AndroidRuntime(24962):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I'm unsure why and not sure how to fix...

Comment: "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"  It's in the stack trace.

Comment: Have you searched for "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag."?

Comment: I tried adding the new task flag in...

Comment: In addition, what context are you calling that on?  That looks to be an adaptor, so the activity that owns the adaptor shouldn't give you that problem.  If you're using the Application context, don't-  use the activity instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
Intent a = new Intent(context, ExpenseInput.class);
a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(a);
```

Comment: Please explain the solution, do not just provide code. Is it just about changing the bitwise operator?

Comment: @Xerus -  Well I thought the code is self explaining.  If you see I have replace tweetypi code snippet with '|' in place of '&'. what explanation do you want in this. '|' is used in intent to append flag not '&'