# Showing clickable link inside of the textView

Tags: java, android, textview, clickable

Does someone know how to show a clickable link inside of the `textView` (or any appropriate view).That `textView` is located inside Recycler row. 
I am getting a string response from JSON feed and inside that string, there is a link to some webpage.
 When the user clicks that link, I want it to open the browser and go to that page. 
Also I am trying to handle that click inside of `onBindViewHolder` method in Recycler View adapter .
 I tried setting `android:autoLink="web"` in xml and `setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` in java for this `textView`, but it doesn't work and gives me this error: 
`" FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want? "`

 If there is a better way for handling these situations, please let me know.

Comment: you need to apply textview with clickable link?

Comment: Could you be more specific. What does apply mean in this context?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258512/trying-to-start-an-activity-is-causing-an-exception-to-be-thrown-unsure-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SpannableString.

For eg: I am going to apply clickable for register text(which has blue color with underlined) means,

```
String text ="Don't have an account? Register";
     SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text);
        spannableString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.blue)), 23, 31, 0);// i am applying for Register alone. so starting count is 23 and end count is 31.
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new SpaceAdjust(text) {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
               //here perform your stuff
            }
        };
        spannableString.setSpan(clickableSpan, 23, 31,
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

if you need to make text clicable with underline. use this method.

```
    import android.text.TextPaint;
    import android.text.style.ClickableSpan;
    import android.view.View;

      /**
       * SpaceAdjust.java
      * 
      * This is the class that is used to display underline text
       */
    public class SpaceAdjust extends ClickableSpan {

     /** The clicked. */
      String clicked;

     /**
      * Instantiates a new space adjust.
      * 
      * @param string
      *            the string
      */
      public SpaceAdjust(String string) {
        super();
        clicked = string;
       }

      /*
       * (non-Javadoc)
       * 
      * @see android.text.style.ClickableSpan#onClick(android.view.View)
      */
      public void onClick(View tv) {
        // Un used Code .. Implemented Method
      }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * android.text.style.ClickableSpan#updateDrawState(android.text.TextPaint)
     */
    public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
        ds.setUnderlineText(true); // if you don't want to use underline text, just make this as false.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:textColorHighlight="@color/RED"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:textColorLink="@color/RED" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
android:linksClickable="true"
```

in your textView

and also onCreate of your activity set

```
 edtLinks.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

where, edtLinks is your TextView.

Moreover, you can also add below at textChangelistner

```
edtLinks.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                        int before, int count) {
                }
            });
```